# Can we install launcher selectively based on check at installation time

Tags: install4j

I have multiple launcher in an application and I want to install it selectively based on a flag provided at installation time, like in GUI mode install one and in unattended mode install another. Can we achieve in Install4j?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the launchers into different file sets and select the file sets programmatically at runtime.

1. You create file sets on the "Files->Define Distribution Tree" step.
2. In the launcher wizard, on the "Executable info" step you can select the file set for the launcher.
3. At runtime, call

   ```
   context.getFileSetById("123").setSelected(false)
   ```

   to prevent the installation of the file set with ID "123".